# cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/if2ip5okvavl8u6jpdtpczuog/merged/app/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping with file

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aurelia

On my Windows machine, I am attempting to build a containerized node.js application with the following Dockerfile:

```docker
  # use latest version of nodejs
  FROM node:lts-alpine
  
  # install aurelia-cli to build the app & http-server to serve static contents
  RUN npm i -g http-server
  RUN npm i -g aurelia-cli
  
  # set working directory to app
  # henceforth all commands will run inside this folder
  WORKDIR /app
  
  # copy package.json related files first and install all required dependencies
  COPY package*.json ./
  RUN npm install
  
  # copy the rest of the files and folders & install dependencies
  COPY . ./
  RUN npm run build
  
  # by default http-server will serve contents on port 8080
  # so we expose this port to host machine
  EXPOSE 8080
  
  CMD [ "http-server" , "dist" ]
```

However, `docker build .`  fails at the line `Copy . ./`. with the message `cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/if2ip5okvavl8u6jpdtpczuog/merged/app/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping with file`.

What do I need to do to get my container image to build?

Comment: That error message seems like it's trying to copy the host system's `node_modules` directory into the image.  The error itself is unusual, but doing that overwrites the results of the previous `RUN docker install` step and can lead to problems if the host and container are different operating systems.  Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the `node_modules` tree?

Comment: Yep, the .dockerignore was missing, and thanks for the more detailed explanation of the underlying problem. Edited my answer to add that as the main suggestion for solving the issue.

Answer (score 21):

Add `node_modules` to a `.dockerignore` file in the same directory as your Dockerfile, as outlined [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/#dockerignore-file): (h/t [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955265/cannot-replace-to-directory-var-lib-docker-overlay2-if2ip5okvavl8u6jpdtpczuog-m#comment128860002_72955265)).

Less gracefully, simply delete the project's `node_modules` directory then rerun `docker build`.

Answer (score 6):

Create file `.dockerignore` and add `node_modules/` and try to build again that should solve the error you facing.